# Add Hexa Values Registry key into powershell script

Tags: outlook, registry, intune

I have query regarding adding hexa values in powershell script for intune script policy, I want to make open sans light font as a default font for outlook of every intune enrolled user. Does anyone has any work around or hint for this?

Firstly set my outlook font style as Open sans light font and then take registry key and put it in the .ps1 script file, make intune script policy and upload this .ps1 file but it doesnt work for me.